# Channel cache is incoherent

Tags: node.js, dictionary, discord, discord.js, synchronization

I've built a few functions to table channel & category information, one of which runs when the bot starts to make sure everything is synced.

The problem I've run into is that `bot.channels.cache` contains channels that no longer exist, or states of a channel that no longer exists. For example, I only have one channel in the server called "general". Yet, there are 3 separate entries for that channel by name, and only one contains the ID (`711043006781849686`) of the current "general" channel:

[image]

```
import Discord from 'discord.js'
import config from '../config.js'

const bot = new Discord.Client({ partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'] })

bot.login(config.botToken)

bot.on('ready', async () => {
  console.log(bot.channels.cache)
}

-- returns --

Collection(46) [Map] {
  ...
  '711043006781849686' => <ref *16> TextChannel {
    type: 'text',
    deleted: false,
    id: '711043006781849686',
    name: 'general',
    rawPosition: 10,
    parentID: '711043007197216880',
    permissionOverwrites: Collection(3) [Map] {
      '711043006253367426' => [PermissionOverwrites],
      '711043006295179347' => [PermissionOverwrites],
      '861109585930747934' => [PermissionOverwrites]
    },
    topic: 'General chat channel.',
    nsfw: false,
    lastMessageID: '860794574707752980',
    rateLimitPerUser: 0,
    lastPinTimestamp: null,
    guild: Guild {
      members: [GuildMemberManager],
      channels: [GuildChannelManager],
      roles: [RoleManager],
      presences: [PresenceManager],
      voiceStates: [VoiceStateManager],
      deleted: false,
      available: true,
      id: '711043006253367426',
      shardID: 0,
      name: 'Omegabox',
      icon: null,
      splash: null,
      discoverySplash: null,
      region: 'us-central',
      memberCount: 5,
      large: false,
      features: [Array],
      applicationID: null,
      afkTimeout: 900,
      afkChannelID: '711043009944223832',
      systemChannelID: '711043006781849686',
      embedEnabled: undefined,
      premiumTier: 0,
      premiumSubscriptionCount: 0,
      verificationLevel: 'NONE',
      explicitContentFilter: 'DISABLED',
      mfaLevel: 0,
      joinedTimestamp: 1589597389528,
      defaultMessageNotifications: 'ALL',
      systemChannelFlags: [SystemChannelFlags],
      maximumMembers: 100000,
      maximumPresences: null,
      approximateMemberCount: null,
      approximatePresenceCount: null,
      vanityURLCode: null,
      vanityURLUses: null,
      description: null,
      banner: null,
      rulesChannelID: null,
      publicUpdatesChannelID: null,
      preferredLocale: 'en-US',
      ownerID: '598729034867933195',
      emojis: [GuildEmojiManager]
    },
    messages: MessageManager {
      cacheType: [class LimitedCollection extends Collection],
      cache: [LimitedCollection [Map]],
      channel: [Circular *16]
    },
    _typing: Map(0) {}
  },
  ...
  '827343616678559757' => <ref *33> TextChannel {
    type: 'text',
    deleted: false,
    id: '827343616678559757',
    name: 'general',
    rawPosition: 0,
    parentID: '827343616678559755',
    permissionOverwrites: Collection(0) [Map] {},
    topic: null,
    lastMessageID: '830245759152291860',
    rateLimitPerUser: 0,
    lastPinTimestamp: null,
    guild: Guild {
      members: [GuildMemberManager],
      channels: [GuildChannelManager],
      roles: [RoleManager],
      presences: [PresenceManager],
      voiceStates: [VoiceStateManager],
      deleted: false,
      available: true,
      id: '827343616678559754',
      shardID: 0,
      name: 'Megabox Emojis 1',
      icon: null,
      splash: null,
      discoverySplash: null,
      region: 'us-west',
      memberCount: 3,
      large: false,
      features: [],
      applicationID: null,
      afkTimeout: 300,
      afkChannelID: null,
      systemChannelID: '827343616678559757',
      embedEnabled: undefined,
      premiumTier: 0,
      premiumSubscriptionCount: 0,
      verificationLevel: 'NONE',
      explicitContentFilter: 'DISABLED',
      mfaLevel: 0,
      joinedTimestamp: 1617380998194,
      defaultMessageNotifications: 'ALL',
      systemChannelFlags: [SystemChannelFlags],
      maximumMembers: 100000,
      maximumPresences: null,
      approximateMemberCount: null,
      approximatePresenceCount: null,
      vanityURLCode: null,
      vanityURLUses: null,
      description: null,
      banner: null,
      rulesChannelID: null,
      publicUpdatesChannelID: null,
      preferredLocale: 'en-US',
      ownerID: '598729034867933195',
      emojis: [GuildEmojiManager]
    },
    messages: MessageManager {
      cacheType: [class LimitedCollection extends Collection],
      cache: [LimitedCollection [Map]],
      channel: [Circular *33]
    },
    nsfw: false,
    _typing: Map(0) {}
  },
  ...
  '827344454259703842' => <ref *34> TextChannel {
    type: 'text',
    deleted: false,
    id: '827344454259703842',
    name: 'general',
    rawPosition: 0,
    parentID: '827344454259703840',
    permissionOverwrites: Collection(0) [Map] {},
    topic: null,
    lastMessageID: '827580681730261032',
    rateLimitPerUser: 0,
    lastPinTimestamp: null,
    guild: Guild {
      members: [GuildMemberManager],
      channels: [GuildChannelManager],
      roles: [RoleManager],
      presences: [PresenceManager],
      voiceStates: [VoiceStateManager],
      deleted: false,
      available: true,
      id: '827344454259703838',
      shardID: 0,
      name: 'Megabox Emojis 2',
      icon: null,
      splash: null,
      discoverySplash: null,
      region: 'us-west',
      memberCount: 3,
      large: false,
      features: [],
      applicationID: null,
      afkTimeout: 300,
      afkChannelID: null,
      systemChannelID: '827344454259703842',
      embedEnabled: undefined,
      premiumTier: 0,
      premiumSubscriptionCount: 0,
      verificationLevel: 'NONE',
      explicitContentFilter: 'DISABLED',
      mfaLevel: 0,
      joinedTimestamp: 1617381010142,
      defaultMessageNotifications: 'ALL',
      systemChannelFlags: [SystemChannelFlags],
      maximumMembers: 100000,
      maximumPresences: null,
      approximateMemberCount: null,
      approximatePresenceCount: null,
      vanityURLCode: null,
      vanityURLUses: null,
      description: null,
      banner: null,
      rulesChannelID: null,
      publicUpdatesChannelID: null,
      preferredLocale: 'en-US',
      ownerID: '598729034867933195',
      emojis: [GuildEmojiManager]
    },
    messages: MessageManager {
      cacheType: [class LimitedCollection extends Collection],
      cache: [LimitedCollection [Map]],
      channel: [Circular *34]
    },
    nsfw: false,
    _typing: Map(0) {}
  }
}
```

I'm aware that there is a category named "General" (ID: `711043007197216880`), but the casing is different which is maintained in an entry. I've filtered that one out, along with everything else that isn't "general" from the above block.

What am I missing here? Possible to sync things up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always have an epiphany right after finally making a post.

Been at this for hours and never realized that in this specific call I'm not specifying what guild, or rather what server. The bot is in multiple servers, and I've already got the current server's ID in the config I'm working with.

Changed `bot.channels.cache` to `bot.guilds.cache.get(config.guildId).channels.cache`.